# Select item using ItemName in AWS simpledb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-simpledb

I've recently started exploring SimpleDB java sdk. and I'm trying to get the item using the ItemName. 
please refer below test code -

```
    val demoItem = Item("id1", listOf(Attribute("fName", "Test7"), Attribute("age", "21")))

    val result = client.select(SelectRequest().withSelectExpression("select * from demo where itemName() = 'id1' "))

    assertEquals(listOf(demoItem), result.items)
```

the result actually returns zero records. I'm not sure about where I'm doing wrong with this query.

PS: I'm able to select item using attribute 'fName' and 'age'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using fake SimpleDB for testing, https://github.com/stephenh/fakesdb

When I go through their code, I found that search by itemName() is not implemented there.

So, when testing against the real SimpleDB I'm able to get the data with itemName().

Closing this question!